# re.sub() - Replace with text from match without using capture groups?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to figure out how I can make python's `re` module behave more like `grep` in colored output.

This means that I need to take an abritrary regex that I have no control over, find it in a string, and then colorize just the match.  Because I have no control over the regex, I can't rely on capture groups for my solution.

For example, if I have:

```
s="omglolwtfbbq"
regex=r"l[\w]"
```

I want python to replace `lo` and `lw` with a string that uses the match in it, *without capture groups in the regex*.  So something like:

```
re.sub(regex, "!%s!", s)
re.sub(regex, "!\0!", s)
re.sub(regex, "!<THE MATCHING STRING>!", s)
```

Would produce:

```
"omg!lo!!lw!tfbbq"
```

Ultimately, I'm simply trying to colorize the portion of `s` that matches the sent regex; grep does this with a simple string input and no capture groups.

Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, `re.sub` allows you to use a function instead of a fixed replacement string. E.g.

```py
>>> s = "omglolwtfbbq"
>>> regex = r"l[\w]"
>>> re.sub(regex, lambda x: "!%s!" % x.group(), s)
'omg!lo!!lw!tfbbq'
```

Note that the `.group` method of a match object returns the whole match (whether or not capture groups are present). If you have capture groups, then `.groups` returns those captured groups.

To answer your question about colouring specifically, I would recommend taking a look at [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for - awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python `re` module does that, instead of which, you can design positive look-arounds to do such `re.sub`, for instance:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'(?=l)', '!', "omglolwtfbbq"))
```

for placing a `!` right before `l`

#### Output

```
omg!lo!lwtfbbq
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sIakDa/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/sIakDa/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Thanks Emma - I updated the question to be more clear about what I'm asking; I don't actually have any control over the sent regex; it's completely arbitrary.